# This lib has a "main": "index.js" but there is no root index.js file. How is this possible to work

Tags: react-native, npm

Lib: [react-native-jsonschema-form](https://github.com/velocitycareerlabs/react-native-jsonschema-form)

How is this possible? What am I missing? Im using metro bundling and running into the logical error `index.js. Indeed, none of these files exist:`